# SQL Count differs

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a SQL query that just count and it returns the correct value, but when i slice it up and get the count for the different areas the total count no longer match the first.

This is what i got:

Table zipcodes, that contain a CountyID, CountyName & Zipcode.

Table Orders that contains ShippingCountry & ShippingZip

The first count looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(STFO.ShippingZip)
FROM Orders
WHERE 
AND STFO.intShippingCountryID = 202
AND STFO.ShippingZip IN (SELECT DISTINCT ZipCode FROM SwedishZipCodes07)
AND STFO.ShippingZip > 0
```

In one example i get this count to 3007 wich is correct.
In my next count it looks more like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CountyName, CountyID,
(SELECT COUNT(STFO.ShippingZip)
FROM Orders
WHERE 
AND STFO.intShippingCountryID = 202
AND STFO.ShippingZip IN (SELECT DISTINCT ZipCode FROM SwedishZipCodes07 WHERE CountyID = ZipWrapper.CountyID)
AND STFO.ShippingZip > 0) AS Count
FROM Zipcodes ZipWrapper
ORDER BY ZipWrapper.CountyID
```

In the very same example i now get count like 3018.
(In my examples the query is filtered more specific but they both match each other, the differences are in my simplified example code here).

Comment: I really cannot understand your english? "now get count like"?? Can you post the queries with their results?

Comment: Yes, you have two different procedures that do two different things.  Was there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: Compare two selects: `SELECT DISTINCT ZipCode FROM SwedishZipCodes07` and `SELECT DISTINCT ZipCode FROM SwedishZipCodes07 WHERE CountyID = ZipWrapper.CountyID`. It looks there could be a problem.

Comment: Aside from the fact, that these statements aren't valid SQL, they are two completely different statements

Comment: @Michas : The distinct in the second is to eliminate duplicate entries of CountyName & CountyID & The same count.

@DanielHilgarth : Yes the SQL Code is simplified and i guess my brain had a melt down yesterday when i copied in code and forgot to eliminate my aliases 'STFO' and souch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have the same STFO.ShippingZip for 2 different CountyIDs.

That's why in the second query it will add to each CountyID and in the first one it is added only once.

Comment: Yes, this vas very much the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
SELECT CountyName, CountyID,
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(STFO.ShippingZip))
    FROM Orders STFO, SwedishZipCodes07
    WHERE STFO.intShippingCountryID = 202
    AND STFO.ShippingZip > 0
    AND STFO.ShippingZip = SwedishZipCodes07.ZipCode
    AND SwedishZipCodes07.CountyId = ZipWrapper.CountyID

) AS Count
FROM Zipcodes ZipWrapper
ORDER BY ZipWrapper.CountyID
```

Comment: This dont work since all members who has the same zipcode will be counted as one. Total count in my example got to 1419 (about half of the correct count).